Get content from text file and save it into a variable - Azure YML
I have a txt file and I'm trying to save all the content in a variable but I'm only getting the first line of the content into the variable
greetings.txt
- hello: 123 
- hello: 456
- hello: 789 

azure-pipeline.yml
variables:
- name: MY_TEXT_FILE
  value: 'greetings.txt'
  readonly: true

# Save text file in this variable
- name: GREETINGS_CONTENT
  value: ''

   steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Save text file content in a variable'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=GREETINGS_CONTENT]$(cat $MY_TEXT_FILE)"

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Another task'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          # This is only printing the first line of the txt file
          # I want to save ALL the txt file content in the variable
          echo "My greetings are: $GREETINGS_CONTENT"

Results after 'Another task' is executed:
Actual results:
- hello: 123

Expected results:
- hello: 123 
- hello: 456
- hello: 789

What I need to update so I can get the expected results?

Is this a learning exercise or are you trying to solve a particular problem? Reading the contents of a text file into a variable is an unusual scenario, and there's probably a more idiomatic way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

There are a few limitations for multi-line variables in DevOps, please check the user voice ticket for this topic: Multiple lines variable in Build and Release.
To solve this issue, we can convert the value to base64 type. Then decode the variable value in the next task.
variables:
- name: MY_TEXT_FILE
  value: 'greetings.txt'
  readonly: true

# Save text file in this variable
- name: GREETINGS_CONTENT
  value: ''

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Save text file content in a variable'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      testcontent=$(cat $MY_TEXT_FILE)
      export test=$(echo "$testcontent"| base64 -w 0)
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=GREETINGS_CONTENT]$test"

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Another task'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      # This is only printing the first line of the txt file
      # I want to save ALL the txt file content in the variable
      export content=$(echo "$(GREETINGS_CONTENT)" | base64 -d -w 0)
      echo $content


Please check similar ticket for your reference.

Hello, I'm getting this error :(
base64: invalid argument -w
Usage: base64 [-hDd] [-b num] [-i in_file] [-o out_file]
-h, --help     display this message
-Dd, --decode   decodes input
-b, --break    break encoded string into num character lines
-i, --input    input file (default: "-" for stdin)
-o, --output   output file (default: "-" for stdout)

It seems like your environment is using a different version of base64 that doesn’t recognize the -w option. Try with export test=$(echo "$testcontent"| base64) and export content=$(echo "$(GREETINGS_CONTENT)" | base64 -d) without -w.  Or try with microsoft-hosted agent.
